# High level language to prototype your program?

Tags: c, algorithm, prototype, high-level

What is a good high level language to prototype your program in for later optimization in c ( structurally similar in terms of function calls and stuff)?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific (if it helps), I am planning to implement the DPLL algorithm.

Comment: related: [Chaff](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3580204). btw, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9287525/edit) your question, you don't need to comment on your own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like python.  It can make use of sockets, ioctl, structs etc. And with ctypes, you can interface with external libs.

Comment: Also because it is dynamic, you can play around with your objects and methods on the fly in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much of the DPLL algorithm, I'd recommend Python as well, but not for the same reasons as tMC (not so relevant here): I'd recommend it for its lightweight syntax and wonderful ease of use of data structures like lists and dictionaries.

Control structures map in a straightforward way to those of C. Simple data structures can map to C structs and arrays; more sohisticated ones can require C++'s STL (or C equivalents). I'd recommend not to take any porting decision until the Python code is fully matured.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Thanks.